# How to display Quantity of Product?

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to count Quantity of Products, how can I do this (in image)?I hope, you understood me. My code does'nt work.
This my code:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i=1;
        SqlCommand seldb = new SqlCommand("Select * from Product where barcode=" + textBox1.Text, conn);
        conn.Open();
        seldb.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader read = seldb.ExecuteReader();
        while (read.Read() == true)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(read.GetValue(0), read.GetValue(1), read.GetValue(2), i);
            for (int j=0;j<=dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1;j++)
            {
                if (textBox1.Text == dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[3].Value = i;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Not this:
[image: Not this]

How to do this?
[image: How do this?]

Comment: Make sure to pass that value from the textbox as a parameter rather than just concatenating the string together. Cleansing your inputs to your database is very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try altering your SQL query to aggregate your quantities.

Replace your command with this one.

```
SqlCommand seldb = new SqlCommand("Select ProductId, Name, Barcode, COUNT(*) as Quantity from Product where barcode =" + textBox1.Text + " Group By ProductId, Name, Barcode", conn);
```

You should actually be using a `using` statement with that as well.

Then you will replace your `i` values with the new `Quantity` column.

Note: Don't forget about Bobby Tables - http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: in Product table there IdProduct, Name and Barcode. but not Quantity

Comment: in datagrid I wnat to show count of Name, which   textBox1.Text == dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value

Comment: It is a correct solution. Also he/she could use `Count` instead of `Sum` and also use parameterized query to avoid SQL Injection. +1.

Comment: @S.Akbari Good call on the `Count` that gets rid of the problem with `Quantity` not being in the database. I updated the answer with that suggestion.

Comment: sorry, how can I do "replace your `i` values with the new `Quantity` column"?

Comment: The same way you are getting the other values from the reader. Something like `read.GetValue(4)` should return the Quantity value